# Isabelle/HOL: proof by 'simp' is slow while 'value' is instantaneous

Tags: performance, isabelle

I am new to Isabelle/HOL, still in the study of the prog-prov exercises. In the meantime, I am exercising by applying these proof techniques to questions of combinatorial words. I observe a very different behavior (in terms of efficiency), between 'value' and 'lemma'.

Can one explain the different evaluation/search strategies between the two commands?

Is there a way to have the speed of 'value' used inside a proof of a 'lemma'?

Of course, I am asking because I have not found the answer in the documentation (so far). What is the manual where this difference of efficiency would be documented and explained?

Here is a minimal piece of source to reproduce the problem.

```
theory SlowLemma
imports Main
begin

(* Alphabet for Motzkin words. *)
datatype alphabet = up | lv | dn

(* Keep the [...] notation for lists. *)
no_notation Cons (infixr "#" 65) and append (infixr "@" 65)

primrec count :: "'a ⇒ 'a list ⇒ nat" where
"count _ Nil = 0" |
"count s (Cons h q) = (if h = s then Suc (count s q) else count s q)"

(* prefix n l simply returns undefined if n > length l. *)
fun prefix :: "'a list ⇒ nat ⇒ 'a list" where
"prefix _ 0 = []" |
"prefix (Cons h q) (Suc n) = Cons h (prefix q n)"

definition M_ex_7 :: "alphabet list" where
"M_ex_7 ≡ [lv, lv, up, up, lv, dn, dn]"
definition M_ex_19 :: "alphabet list" where
"M_ex_19 ≡ [lv, lv, up, up, lv, up, lv, dn, lv, dn, lv, up, dn, dn, lv, up, dn, lv, lv]"

fun height :: "alphabet list ⇒ int" where
"height w = (int (count up w + count up w)) - (int (count dn w + count dn w))"

primrec is_pre_M :: "alphabet list ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
"is_pre_M _ (0 :: nat) = True"
| "is_pre_M w (Suc n) = (let w' = prefix w (Suc n) in is_pre_M w' n ∧ height w' ≥ 0)"

fun is_M :: "alphabet list ⇒ bool" where
"is_M w = (is_pre_M w (length w) ∧ height w = 0)"

(* These two calls to value are fast. *)
value "is_M M_ex_7"
value "is_M M_ex_19"

(* This first lemma goes fast. *)
lemma is_M_M_ex_7: "is_M M_ex_7"
by (simp add: M_ex_7_def)

(* This second lemma takes five minutes. *)
lemma is_M_M_ex_19: "is_M M_ex_19"
by (simp add: M_ex_19_def)

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`simp` is a proof method that goes through the proof kernel, i.e., every step has to be justified. For long rewriting chains, this may be quite expensive.

On the other hand, `value` uses the [code generator](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/codegen.pdf) where possible. All used constants are translated into ML code, which is then executed. You have to trust the result, i.e., it didn't go through the kernel and may be wrong.

The equivalent of `value` as a proof method is `eval`. Thus, an easy way to speed up your proofs is to use this:

```
lemma is_M_M_ex_19: "is_M M_ex_19"
by eval
```

Opinions in the Isabelle community about whether or not this should be used differ. Some say it's similar to `axiomatization` (because you have to trust it), others consider it a reasonable way if going through the kernel is prohibitively slow. Everyone agrees though that you have to be really careful about custom setup of the code generator (which you haven't done, so it should be fine).

There's middle ground: the `code_simp` method will set up `simp` to use *only* the equations that would otherwise be used by `eval`. That means: a much smaller set of rules for `simp`, while still going through the kernel. In your case, it is actually the same speed as `by eval`, so I would highly recommend doing that:

```
lemma is_M_M_ex_19: "is_M M_ex_19"
by code_simp
```

In your case, the reason why `code_simp` is much faster than `simp` is because of a simproc that has exponential runtime in the number of nested `let` expressions. Hence, another solution would be to use `simp add: Let_def` to just unfold `let` expressions.

---

*Edited to reflect comment by Andreas Lochbihler*

Comment: The difference between `code_simp` and `simp` is due to the simproc `let_simp`, whose run-time is exponential in the nesting depth of `let`. If you add `Let_def` to the simplifier's simpset, `simp` can also prove `is_M_M_ex_19` in a short amount of time.

Comment: I had overlooked the need to unfold `let` constructs. Another solution (which explains me more about the phenomenon) is to replace the second case of my original definition of `is_pre_M` by `"is_pre_M w (Suc n) = (is_pre_M (prefix w (Suc n)) n ∧ height (prefix w (Suc n)) ≥ 0)"`.

Comment: @AndreasLochbihler I've updated my answer based on your comment.